# I'm getting some error while creating database android

Tags: android, database

I'm trying to create database using [this](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html) tutorial. I'm still new in android developing, so probably this is something very easy, but still learning. This is the error i'm getting:

```
07-19 14:37:18.235: E/SQLiteLog(9089): (1) no such table: grocery
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089): Process: com.dusandimitrijevic.grocerylist, PID: 9089
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dusandimitrijevic.grocerylist/com.dusandimitrijevic.grocerylist.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: grocery (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, price FROM grocery
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: grocery (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, price FROM grocery
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1093)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:670)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1440)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1287)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1158)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1326)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at com.dusandimitrijevic.data.GroceryDbAdapter.fetchAllItems(GroceryDbAdapter.java:145)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at com.dusandimitrijevic.grocerylist.MainActivity.fillData(MainActivity.java:79)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at com.dusandimitrijevic.grocerylist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
07-19 14:37:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(9089):     ... 10 more
```

Here is the code of my **Database**:

```
package com.dusandimitrijevic.data;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Simple notes database access helper class. Defines the basic CRUD operations
 * for the notepad example, and gives the ability to list all notes as well as
 * retrieve or modify a specific note.
 * 
 * This has been improved from the first version of this tutorial through the
 * addition of better error handling and also using returning a Cursor instead
 * of using a collection of inner classes (which is less scalable and not
 * recommended).
 */
public class GroceryDbAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

    private static final String TAG = "GroceryDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private Context mCtx;

    /**
     * Database creation sql statement
     */
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table grocery (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "title text not null, price text not null);";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "grocery";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     * 
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public GroceryDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    /**
     * Open the notes database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
     * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
     * signal the failure
     * 
     * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
     *         initialization call)
     * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
     */
    public GroceryDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }


    /**
     * Create a new note using the title and body provided. If the note is
     * successfully created return the new rowId for that note, otherwise return
     * a -1 to indicate failure.
     * 
     * @param title the title of the note
     * @param body the body of the note
     * @return rowId or -1 if failed
     */
    public long createItem(String title, String price) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PRICE, price);

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    /**
     * Delete the note with the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of note to delete
     * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean deleteItem(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor over the list of all notes in the database
     * 
     * @return Cursor over all notes
     */
    public Cursor fetchAllItems() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_PRICE}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor positioned at the note that matches the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of note to retrieve
     * @return Cursor positioned to matching note, if found
     * @throws SQLException if note could not be found/retrieved
     */
    public Cursor fetchItem(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_TITLE, KEY_PRICE}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    /**
     * Update the note using the details provided. The note to be updated is
     * specified using the rowId, and it is altered to use the title and body
     * values passed in
     * 
     * @param rowId id of note to update
     * @param title value to set note title to
     * @param body value to set note body to
     * @return true if the note was successfully updated, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean updateItem(long rowId, String title, String price) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        args.put(KEY_PRICE, price);

        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

I'm still learning, so any help or advice would be appricieated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, you change the SQL statement defined in your *DATABASE_CREATE* String and than you change your database version.

Changing the database version, `onUpgrade()` is called and the SQL statement inside it is called:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
```

This try to remove a table the probably does not exists.

Then the `onCreate()` is called and you try to create a table, but since it probably already exsists, nothing happen, but your table remains the one you created in the version 1.

So, the solutions can either be:

1. Unistall the app from your device and reinstall it (the previous version of the database will be deleted)
2. Remove the instruction:

   ```
   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
   ```

   and use:

   ```
   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS grocery");
   ```

Comment: That worked for me, but can you help me just with something else. I'm getting nullpointerexception on setting adapter to listView and in method i'm trying to create SimpleCursorAdapter is depracted. This is the method where i'm getting an error: @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") SimpleCursorAdapter items =  new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_row, itemsCursor, from, to); listView.setAdapter(items); 
 }

Comment: Method is called fillData

Comment: It seems right. However It is pretty hard formulate a questions and answers in the comment. I suggest you to ask a new question.

Comment: I have created new question. Can you please see it and look if you can help me with that. here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31504592/simplecursoradapter-isnt-working)

Answer (score -1):

In your DATABASE_CREATE query remove semicolon that is inside the string It is causing error

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table grocery (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "title text not null, price text not null)";//removed which was semicolon inside it
```

Comment: Putting a semicolon at the end of a SQL statement is absolutely legal