# SimpleCursorAdapter isn't working

Tags: android

I have been following one of google developers [tutorials](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html) about creating an application with storing added items to database and retriving them to listView, but they are using ListActivity for extending their MainActivity and i'm using my BaseActivity to extend MainActivity. I'm getting error on passing adapter to List. Also my simpleCursorAdapter and startManagingCursor are depracted.

**Here is my code:**

```
import com.dusandimitrijevic.data.GroceryDbAdapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

    private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

    private GroceryDbAdapter mDbHelper;

    Button addItem;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame_container);

         // inflate the custom activity layout
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View activityView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null,false);

        frameLayout.addView(activityView);

        // Setting toolbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDbHelper = new GroceryDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();


        // Locate ListView
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        fillData();

        addItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        addItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

            }
        });

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void fillData() {
        Cursor itemsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllItems();
        startManagingCursor(itemsCursor);

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
        String[] from = new String[]{GroceryDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.title};

        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        SimpleCursorAdapter items = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_row, itemsCursor, from, to);
        listView.setAdapter(items);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, "Add Item");
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case INSERT_ID:
                createItem();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, "Delete Item");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case DELETE_ID:
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                mDbHelper.deleteItem(info.id);
                fillData();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void createItem() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AddActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AddActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(GroceryDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        fillData();
    }
}
```

**And this is their code:**

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2008 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.android.demo.notepad3;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;

public class Notepadv3 extends ListActivity {
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

    private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

    private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notes_list);
        mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        fillData();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }

    private void fillData() {
        Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
        startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
        String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, notesCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case INSERT_ID:
                createNote();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case DELETE_ID:
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id);
                fillData();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void createNote() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
        i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        fillData();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

*AddActivity.java:*

```
    package com.dusandimitrijevic.grocerylist;


import com.dusandimitrijevic.data.GroceryDbAdapter;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AddActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private Long mRowId;
    private GroceryDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private EditText title_edit;
    private EditText price_edit;
    private Button saveButton;

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDbHelper = new GroceryDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        setContentView(R.layout.add_activity_layout);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Locate the EditText in add_note.xml
        title_edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleEdit);
        price_edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.priceEdit);

        mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null :
            (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(GroceryDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
        if (mRowId == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(GroceryDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)
                                    : null;
        }

        populateFields();

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }

        });

    }

    private void populateFields() {
        if (mRowId != null) {
            Cursor item = mDbHelper.fetchItem(mRowId);
            startManagingCursor(item);
            title_edit.setText(item.getString(
                    item.getColumnIndexOrThrow(GroceryDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
            price_edit.setText(item.getString(
                    item.getColumnIndexOrThrow(GroceryDbAdapter.KEY_PRICE)));
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        saveState();
        outState.putSerializable(GroceryDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        saveState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        populateFields();
    }

    private void saveState() {
        String title = title_edit.getText().toString();
        String price = price_edit.getText().toString();

        if (mRowId == null) {
            long id = mDbHelper.createItem(title, price);
            if (id > 0) {
                mRowId = id;
            }
        } else {
            mDbHelper.updateItem(mRowId, title, price);
        }
    }

}
```

**ERROR I'M GETTING:**

*This is the error i'm getting when i click on addItem button, but nothing also happens when i click on menu option ''add item'' which i declare in onCreateOption*

```
    07-20 00:01:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(27613): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 00:01:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(27613): Process: com.dusandimitrijevic.grocerylist, PID: 27613
07-20 00:01:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(27613): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dusandimitrijevic.grocerylist/com.dusandimitrijevic.grocerylist.AddActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
07-20 00:01:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(27613):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
07-20 00:01:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(27613):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
07-20 00:01:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(27613):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
07-20 00:01:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(27613):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
07-20 00:01:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(27613):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-20 00:01:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(27613):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
07-20 00:01:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(27613):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
07-20 00:01:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(27613):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-20 00:01:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(27613):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-20 00:01:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(27613):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
07-20 00:01:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(27613):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
07-20 00:01:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(27613): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
07-20 00:01:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(27613):    at com.dusandimitrijevic.grocerylist.AddActivity.onCreate(AddActivity.java:48)
07-20 00:01:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(27613):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
07-20 00:01:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(27613):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
07-20 00:01:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(27613):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
07-20 00:01:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(27613):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Post what euro you're getting.

Comment: 07-19 21:04:32.912: E/AndroidRuntime(27600): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dusandimitrijevic.grocerylist/com.dusandimitrijevic.grocerylist.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting a NullPointerException is because you're calling `listView.setAdapter(items);` before calling `listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);`.

Just move the call to `fillData()` below the call that initializes `listView`:

```
    mDbHelper = new GroceryDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    //fillData(); //don't call it here

    // Locate ListView
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    fillData(); //call it here
```

As for your next NullPointerException, you need to initialize `saveButton` before you call `saveButton.setOnClickListener()`.

Something like this:

```
saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButtonIdHere);

saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }

        });
```

Comment: that solved my problem, but now i'm getting some NullPointerException on my addItem button where i'm calling new activity for adding item, and also my menu add option do nothing. Nothing happens when i click on it. It should intent to my AddActivity.class, and button too.

Comment: I have edited my question and added the code from AddActivity.java

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic Just updated the answer, you just need to initialize your Button.

Comment: That was it. Now everything is working except this onOptionItem i set which is calling the same actvitiy as addItem button. Do you have any suggestion about that?

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic Nothing immediately obvious just from looking at it.  If you can't figure it out, open up a new question with all the relevant info of the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call method:

fillData()

after this assignment:

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list).